# Meteor collection trouble

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

First off, sorry for being a complete javascript noob, I am more of a PHP guy and am just testing out the meteor framework.

I am trying to loop through a collection of objects and trying to add a property from another collections as so :

```
Template.host.hosts = function() {
    var hosts = Hosts.find();

    hosts.forEach(function(host) {
        host.lastPing = Pings.findOne({id: host.id}, {sort: {timestamp : -1}});

        // This works fine
        // console.log(host.lastPing.id);
    });

    for (host in hosts) {

        // This results in "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
        console.log(host.lastPing.id);
    }

    return hosts;
};
```

I don't understand why the second console.log is not working.

I have tried searching but I don't know if the problem is specific to the way meteor handles collections or the way I should be adding properties to a javascript object or someting completely unrelated (scope etc...)

I have simplified my problem to try to understand what is happening, my real problem is obviously looping in a template as per :

```
{{#each hosts}}
    {{this.lastPing.id}}
{{/each}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. MongoDB and Meteor ids are stored in `_id` rather than `id`.
2. In the context of your `forEach` method, `host` iterates through the query set returned by `Hosts.find()`, but it doesn't actually give you access to the documents themselves.  Essentially, it's a copy of the information in the MongoDB rather than the document in the database.

   The correct (and only) way to update the actual document is by using the [Collection.update](https://docs.meteor.com/#update) method:

   ```
   Hosts.update({_id: host._id}, {$set: {lastPing: Pings.findOne({id: host.id}, {sort: {timestamp : -1}}) }});
   ```

   (note that you can only update by `_id` on the client which is why that's what I've used here, whereas you can supply any query on the server.)
3. The `hosts` object is a *cursor* rather than an *array*.  This means that when you use `for host in hosts`, you're actually iterating through the properties of the cursor object (which are inherited from the prototype) rather than an array of hosts, and none of them has an id property.  One way to make this work is to fetch the query set and put it into `hosts` like this:

   ```
   var hosts = Hosts.find().fetch();
   ```

   Alternatively, you can stick with the cursor and use `forEach` again, although you'll either have to rewind it with `hosts.rewind()`, or repeat the line above to reset it to the start of the query set.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much Hosts.update did the trick, I am going to have to re-read this detailed post again a few times to fully understand.